# Difference between an interaction and eventListener in OpenLayers

Tags: openlayers, event-listener, ol-interaction

I am wondering when should I use an interaction instead of an eventListener.

For example I can have a handler function like this:

```
function handler(evt) {
   if (evt.type === 'click') {
      console.log(evt);
   }
   return true;
}
```

And then add it as a click listener to my map:

```
myMap.on('click', handler);
```

Or have an interaction like this:

```
var interaction = new ol.interaction.Interaction({
   handleEvent: handler
});
```

And add the interaction to my map:

```
myMap.addInteraction(interaction);
```

That gives me the exact same result and exact same `ol.MapBrowserPointerEvent` is logged in the console.

So what is an interaction for? (except predefined interaction like zoom etc.)